# Can I output a raw HTML/CSS/JS file using Razor/Razor engine

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to build a character sheet for roll20. While I understand I can use other systems for this, I am trying to learn C# and I figured doing this using C# and Razor would be an interesting challenge.

However, to run on roll20, I need at most a js file, a css file, and an html file. I am trying to find a way to output to files in a specific directory. Is this at all possible and if so how would I do it? I'm trying to investigate this before wasting my time on something that isn't possible, and searching through the internet all describe using a server render, which is not possible with what I'm doing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how "render Razor output to a directory" isn't specific?

Comment: Razor views (and as a by product, using the Razor engine) requires a server or application that sits behind the front-end output. Razor views are `compiled`, meaning it takes C# and web tech and converts that into exclusively browser-supported code. You need code-behind to use Razor, it's not a standalone technology for the browser.

Comment: No problem. You can use Razor to render HTML files as long as you have an application behind doing so, you don't need a full ASP.NET application. I've done similar things for PDFs and emails using Razor, but yeah as stated it's not a a browser technology unfortunately.